# Is it possible to give height & width in input button tag where no style sheets are used?

Tags: html

i'm trying to give height & width in input button tag . But it's not working. how can i solve this problem? (that no style sheets are allowed)

```html
<input type="button" name="" value="HOME" height="600" width="600" >
```

Comment: For clarification, by “css not allowed” do you mean that inline styles (`<input type="button" name="" style=“...”>`) are not allowed, or that no style sheets are allowed?

Comment: that no style sheets are allowed

Comment: Weight? Did you mean width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are writing works well if the input button is an image but the height and width should be put in style tag if you wish to work on a simple button tag.

see code below

`<input type="button" name="" value="HOME" style="height:600px; width:"600px" >`